# Hall effect - chip identification

Tags: identification, hall-effect

I'm playing with Hall effect sensors and wanted to identify this one. I got it magnified but I've never seen anything like it.

Is it a code for something, or has it been removed off the surface?

I managed to put it in photoshop and draw dots over it and got the following 2d bar code.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to match anything online.. thoughts?

[image: Close up of Hall effect sensor]

[image: 2d-code]

Comment: For some more context: What is it mounted on? What device is it used in?

Comment: this chip is SMT mounted on a little board.  I pulled it out of a device that detects a magnet inside a water consumption meter..

Comment: Looks like a 2D barcode.   https://www.gs1.org/barcodes/2d

Comment: it does look like a bar code, what type of device could read it?

Comment: please update the picture ..... rotate couterclockwise about 40  degrees so that the dot grid is not at an angle, and take a higher resolution picture .... also adjust the light so that the dots are more clear

Comment: I've updated the pic

Comment: Unfortunately the barcode is not legible enough to get a good read.  If you can take a picture that produces a clear barcode you may be able to plug it in here: https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/ and google the result.

Comment: Brighter, more diffuse lighting from a steeper angle should do it.

Comment: I've used paint on it, and the barcode says "2776181452270009", how useful.

Comment: I got the same code using photoshop, unfortunately it doesn't match anything

Comment: What is the package? It is possible that only one or two manufacturers make a hall sensor in that particular package. After narrowing it down, it may be possible to infer the chip based on the power/ground pin positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Probably an ST [LIS3MDLTR](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/54/2a/85/76/e3/97/42/18/DM00075867.pdf/files/DM00075867.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00075867.pdf) 3-axis magnetoresistive (not Hall) sensor.

[image]

Image from [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Hall-Sensor_STMicroelectronics-LIS3MDLTR_C478483.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 2D code on integrated circuits is often used for tracking purposes. If a device fails, the code can be used to figure out when the chip was manufactured, what wafer batch was used, etc. This is used for quality control purpoes. So the 2D code is likely not going to help you much. I've been trying to find something searching "Signal AJ" but nothing meaningful came up.